# background-image: linear-gradient not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari, background-image, linear-gradients

I got an issue on many pages of my website, but here is one as an example: https://mypieceofcakemove.com/storage/

In the hero section of the page I used Avada theme's option to create a linear-gradient over my background image.

It works well on my desktop and even in inspect tool when I open a preview for iPhone:
[image: Google Chrome browser]

But when I open the page in Safari, it looks like this and since there is no gradient background, the text is barely visible:
[image]

Could you please help me to solve this? Is it an issue related to browser support of linear-gradient?
[image: https://caniuse.com/?search=linear-gradient]

Here is my code:

```
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
background-image: url(https://mypieceofcakemove.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/hero-bg-best-storage-nyc.jpg);
background-image: linear-gradient(
180deg
, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%),url(https://mypieceofcakemove.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/hero-bg-best-storage-nyc.jpg);
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-top: -156px;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 1):

This **is** related to iOS partially supporting `linear-gradient` as `background-image` prior to 15.3 version.

You can add color on top of an image using pseudo element:

```css
.block::before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And if you want to use this fallback only when it's needed, you can use `@support`:

```css
.block {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%),
    url(https://mypieceofcakemove.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/hero-bg-best-storage-nyc.jpg
  );
}

@support not (background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%)) {
  .block::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Here you check if certain rule is supported by a browser. If not, it uses provided rules.